# Why does "select many" on query syntax not work with join

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

An Invoice has many products and a product can have many X (X shall not be important here)

```
var query = from i in invoices
            join prod in i.products on i.id equals prod.InvoiceId
            select new MyClass{ Id = i.id, more props }
```

Why does the join not work?

I get the error that "i.product" The "i" here does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` is for when you have two separate collections, where you want to compare some properties of the various elements of those collections. You can use it when you have a separate unfiltered collection of products, and you want to find products that match on invoice ID. For instance, you might use it if you didn't define any navigation properties.

That's not what you're after here: you do have a navigation property, and by using that, Entity Framework will have set up things so that `i.products` only contains the matching products. You don't need to link on invoice ID manually.

```
var query = from i in invoices
            from prod in i.products
            select ...;
```